# ¿Cómo actúa exactamente el comando sed "${nLinea} s/:[^:]*/:${contrasena}/"?

Tags: shell-script, sed

Para un proyecto necesito crear un alta de usuarios con diferentes tipos de usuarios y funciones este registro de los usuarios se guarda en un archivo de texto con el formato:

```
Nombre:Contraseña:TipodeUsuario:cedula
```

Este registro se hace correctamente y mi duda en cuestión es en la modificación de este registro la cual la hago con un comando sed que no entiendo exactamente que es lo que hace la línea:

```
echo $(sed "${nLinea} s/:[^:]*/:${contrasena}/" usuarios.txt) > usuarios.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trata de leer el manual de sed para tener la información oficial. Por mi parte, te puedo explicar que en:

```
$ echo $(sed "${nLinea} s/:[^:]*/:${contrasena}/" usuarios.txt) > usuarios.txt
```

Vamos a descomponer el comando en varias partes quedándonos únicamente con lo de adentro del *command substitution*, es decir:

```
sed "${nLinea} s/:[^:]*/:${contrasena}/" usuarios.txt
```

De aquí, podemos abstraer el script de `sed` de esta manera:

```
"${nLinea} s/:[^:]*/:${contrasena}/<flag>"
|________| ||______||_____________|  |__ Flag que opera sobre
     |     |   |           |             las coincidencias
 Número    | El patrón     |
           |               |
           |           La cadena
           |
   Comando que indica una
   sustitución de un patrón por
   una cadena
```

En el manual de `sed`, en la sección de `Addresses`, se indica que cuando se antepone un número, esta parte del script se ejecutará únicamente en el número de línea indicada.

Con el comando `s`, sobre esta línea con el número elegido, se buscará el patrón, `:[^:]*`, el cual será tomado por el motor de regex de `sed` como "Después de dos puntos, encuentra todos los caracteres que no sean el caracter ':' (dos puntos)".

Después de encontrar este patrón, se sustituirá por la cadena:

```
:<variable "contrasena">
```

Al no poner ninguna especificación de dirección después del comando `s/regexp/pattern/<flag>`, sólo se aplicará en la **primera coincidencia** de este patrón. Es decir, si encuentra unos primeros dos puntos, entonces se aplicará **únicamente** la sustitución en la **primera coincidencia** del patrón sin puntos consecuente. En otras palabras, esta sustitución se aplicará en el segundo campo en un archivo con el formato de la forma:

```
campo1:campo2:campo3 ...
```

Ya que "campo1", no lo toma en cuenta por no tener puntos, pero ":campo2", ya lo toma en cuenta como el primer encuentro.

Podemos decir que, si tenemos un archivo de la forma:

```
uno1:dos1:tres1:cuatro1
uno2:dos2:tres2:cuatro2
uno3:dos3:tres3:cuatro3
```

Al que le apliquemos un `sed '2 s/:[^:]*/:nueva_contrasena/' archivo_prueba`, obtendremos la sustitución en la segunda línea:

```
uno1:dos1:tres1:cuatro1
uno2:nueva_contrasena:tres2:cuatro2
uno3:dos3:tres3:cuatro3
```

En cambio, si jugamos con, `sed '3 s/:[^:]*/:nueva_contrasena/2' archivo_prueba`, ahora sabemos que `sed` se centrará en la tercera linea, para luego buscar la **segunda coincidencia** del patrón "Dos puntos, seguidos de varios caracteres que no son puntos", es decir:

```
uno1:dos1:tres1:cuatro1
uno2:dos2:tres2:cuatro2
uno3:dos3:nueva_contrasena:cuatro3
    |___||_______________||______|
      |          |            |
   Primera      Segunda      Tercera - Coincidencias
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta me fue muy util

Comment: Tal vez tenga que ahondar un poco más en la explicación de la expresión regular.